# pad_token_id not working in hugging face transformers

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, huggingface-transformers

I want to download the GPT-2 model and tokeniser. For open-end generation, HuggingFace sets the padding token ID to be equal to the end-of-sentence token ID, so I configured it manually using :

```
import tensorflow as tf
from transformers import TFGPT2LMHeadModel, GPT2Tokenizer

tokenizer = GPT2Tokenizer.from_pretrained("gpt2")
model = TFGPT2LMHeadModel.from_pretrained("gpt2", pad_token_id=tokenizer.eos_token_id)
```

However, it gives me the following error:

> TypeError: ('Keyword argument not understood:', 'pad_token_id')

I haven't been able to find a solution for this nor do I understand why I am getting this error. Insights will be appreciated.

Comment: "HuggingFace sets the padding token ID to be equal to the end-of-sentence token ID" - Where do you find this information? Also, AFAIK, this should be set for the tokenizer, not the model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code does not throw any error for me - I would try re-installing the most recent version of `transformers` - if that is a viable solution for you.

Comment: Yes. I made it work. For some reason it doesn't work on Jupyter notebook but works fine when I run python through my terminal.

Comment: @John the jupyter kernel might be using a different virtual environment.